# How to create a FOR loop that will work for calculating instrument scale length and put it in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, variables

I am trying to write a JavaScript program that will accept user input, that being the Scale Length used for their guitar, and how many frets it has, then do the necessary calculations to solve for the distance between each fret.

How I would prefer it to work is the variables would be created as needed. So the user inputs their scale and frets, and the program will display an HTML table with everything, and only display rows for the number of frets they originally input.

The problem is, I'm completely new to JavaScript, and how not the slightest idea how to accomplish this, other than knowing a FOR loop is involved.

EDIT: The values are now calculating correctly, as well as entering into the table correctly! Here's my updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Banjo Neck Calculations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody id="scaleLengthTable">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" id="tableHeader"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fret</th>
                    <th>Distance From Nut</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <script> // Calculates the the scale length
        let scaleLength = prompt("What is your desired scale length?"); // Prompts user for the scale length of their instrument
        let numFrets = prompt("How many frets will you have?"); //Prompts user for the number of frets on their instrument
        let testing = 0; // Placeholder value, updated by the below for loop
        let distFromNut = 0; // Placeholder value, updated by the below for loop
        const fretDists = []; // An array that is filled with values by the below for loop
        let main_table = document.getElementById("scaleLengthTable");

        for (let i = 0; i < numFrets; i++) {
            // Create new row and cells for the table
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            let cell1 = document.createElement("td");
            let cell2 = document.createElement("td");

            testing = (scaleLength - distFromNut) / 17.817;
            fretDists.push(testing);
            distFromNut = fretDists[i] + distFromNut;

            // Add the cells to the row and the row to the table body
            cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
            cell2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(distFromNut.toFixed(4) + '"'));
            row.appendChild(cell1);
            row.appendChild(cell2);
            main_table.appendChild(row);
            
            document.getElementById("tableHeader").innerHTML = "Scale Length = " + scaleLength + '" -  ' + numFrets + " Frets";
        }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    
    
    
</html>
```

Comment: You technically can create variables in JavaScript, but neither is it recommended or easy. It would be better to use an array with the values in it.

Comment: Also, I know nothing about guitars, so to be correct, is the scale length meant to change? And the distance from nut? Also the distance between frets?

Comment: @ArcadeSmasher you are right to question this. The scale length is not meant to change and doesn't change. I was going to ask the OP what is meant by "that being the Scale Length used for their guitar".

Comment: @ArcadeSmasher So if I created an array, I could do with with "calculated" values, right? Then reference a certain position within an array when I need to print it or call it for another calculation?

Comment: @ArcadeSmasher Also, no the scale on a certain guitar does not change, but the scale will very between guitars from different manufacturers, as well as other instruments such as banjos, mandolins, etc.

Comment: @GetSet Refer to my most recent comment to ArcadeSmasher

Comment: Even with clarity on the scale (there isn't, I'm still confused what you mean), what is it that you are trying to achieve? Could you update your question and provide example output? For example, a table without any formatting, just plaintext of desired output for a particular set of input? Foremost you have an algorithm problem to solve. The html/css/js bit is secondary.

Comment: @GetSet My desired end result is much more complex than just determining the length between frets, but those calculations are needed to reach my end result. Everything after that is literally just going to be behind-the-scenes math, and nothing else.

There are calculators available for the scale length, but I need the raw data for what I am trying to accomplish, so these pre-existing calculators won't work for my end result. Here is one such calculator: https://www.stewmac.com/fret-calculator/

Comment: I see. There's lots of ways to solve it. Learn about creating arrays as @ArcadeSmasher mentions. In particular look into this syntax `a = []` and the `push()` method. Yes you'll need a loop e.g. `for (let i = 0; i < numFrets; i++)`. On each iteration of the loop, perform the calculation for the fret (0 --> fret 1, 1 --> fret 2, ...) and store the results to your array using the push method. Really you need to start with the fundamentals. How you then get that all on screen also has various paths. I'll come up with a basic example as an answer below.

Comment: I got it to work, kinda....it's making the calculations I needed. Still gotta figure out how to make it "pretty", but it calculates and prints correctly!

Comment: I updated my original post with my new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in HTML I would create a simple table

```xml
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody id="main-table">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Then in your JavaScript you can add table rows and cells

```js
let main_table = document.getElementById("main-table");

for (let i = 0; i < numFrets; i++) {
    // Create new row and cells for the table
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    let cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    let cell2 = document.createElement("td");

    testing = (scaleLength - distFromNut) / 17.817;
    fretDists.push(testing);
    distFromNut = fretDists[i] + distFromNut;

    // Add the cells to the row and the row to the table body
    cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
    cell2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(distFromNut.toFixed(4)));
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    main_table.appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: I've made these changes, and will be updating my code!

Answer (score 1):

Below you will find a working snippet. I replaced your `prompt()`s by numeric input fields. As soon as there is valid input in both of them the calculation in the function `calc()` is triggered and the results are shown in the table.

Admittedly, there are quite a few concepts in the script that might be new for a "newbie" but I consider them as well worth learning.

```js
const el={}, tbd=document.querySelector("#table tbody");
["scaleLength","numFrets"].forEach(n=>{
 el[n]=document.querySelector(`input[name=${n}]`);
 el[n].addEventListener("input",calc);
});
function calc(){
 let scaleLength=el.scaleLength.value,
     numFrets   =el.numFrets.value,
     distsFromNut=[];
 if(scaleLength>0 && numFrets>0){
  for (let i=0,fret,len=scaleLength; i < numFrets; i++) {
   fret=len/17.817153;
   len-=fret;   distsFromNut.push([scaleLength-len,fret]);
  }
  tbd.innerHTML=distsFromNut.map((d,i)=>
   `<tr><td>${i+1}</td>${d.map(v=>`<td>${v.toFixed(4)}</td>`).join("")}</tr>`
  ).join("\n");
 }
}
calc();
```

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#ddd}
td:nth-child(2) {text-align:right}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="scaleLength" placeholder="Scale length" value="800">
<input type="number" name="numFrets" placeholder="Number of frets" value="12">
<table id="table">
 <thead><tr><th>no.</th><th>dist. from nut</th><th>fret length</th</tr></th></thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

When you put the snippet into action on your own page, please make sure that you place the `<script>` section *below* your `<body>` since the script expects the DOM to have loaded already.